# How to properly pass $index in Bootstrap data target?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, vue.js, v-for

I created dynamic ids using v-for index,
the problem is when I'm trying to use Bootstrap's
data-target to link the div

This doesn't work:

```html
<button data-toggle="collapse" data-target="'#demo'+{{$index}}">EXPAND</button> 

<div v-bind:id="['demo'+index]" class="collapse">
    {{service.sotto[index]}}
</div>
```

So how to properly use data-target + index?

Comment: Have you tried `v-bind:data-target="'#demo'+{{$index}}"`?

Comment: Also the square brackets in `v-bind:id="['demo'+index]"` don't feel right.

Comment: thank you for the suggestion @LukaszWiktor,  v-bind:id with square brackets work fine, v-bind:data-target="'#demo'+{{$index}} instead give me the error "- invalid expression:"

Answer (score 9, accepted):

found it!

```
:data-target="'#demo' + index"
```

Comment: Alternatively, you should also be able to do `data-target="#demo{{$index}}"`

Comment: You could use `:data-target="\`#demo${index}\`"`

Comment: And think Id can be used like `<div :id="'demo'+index">`